# Get all td-tags with colspan="2" into list

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I need to extract all td-tags from `HTML-page` into a list.

I need to filter the results by `colspan="2"`.

This is, what I did so far with HTML agility pack. Unfortunately it is not working.

```
var tdList = from d in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
             where d.Name == "td" &&  d.Attributes["colspan"].Value == "2"
             select d;
```

Comment: Explain 'is not working' , any errors?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple XPath expression:

```
string source = @"<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan='1' id='td1'>no</td>
                    <td colspan='2' id='td2'>yes1</td>
                    <td colspan='2' id='td3'>yes2</td>
                    <td colspan='2' id='td4'>yes3</td>
                    <td colspan='1' id='td5'>no</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>";

HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(source);
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@colspan='2']");
nodes.Select(x=> x.InnerText).Dump();
```

Output:

> Yes1 Yes2 Yes3

[LinqPad Demo](http://share.linqpad.net/knflsi.linq)

**EDIT:**
I've just tested your code and it is working just fine with my dummy source data document. If there is any other malfunction you should properly edit and reword your question.